# Basic Python Script If Statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am messing around with this basic Magic 8 Ball program and im trying to make it only allow yes or no questions I am thinking that it will only except questions that have the first word  "will" or  "do" how can I make a  that only allows those to words?

Here is the Script:

```
import random
import time
print "Welcome to Magic Eight Ball !"
while True:
    def Magic8(a):
        foo = ['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe', 'Doubtful', 'Try Again']
        from random import choice
        print choice(foo)


    a = raw_input("Question: ")
    if a == "exit":
        exit()
    #If Stament here
    print "Determining Your Future..."
    time.sleep(2)
    Magic8(a)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if a.split(None, 1)[0].lower() in {'will', 'do'}:
    print "Determining Your Future..."
    time.sleep(2)
    magic8(a) # function names are usually not capitalized
```

[`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits the sentence on whitespace, [`str.lower`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) should handle the uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.startswith` and pass a tuple of accepted words.

```
if a.lower().startswith(("will ", "do ")):
   # Do your magic.
```

Comment: Nice, and simpler than my answer, but you probably have to add a space there: `'will '`, `'do '`, otherwise there can be false positives: `'William is a unicorn'`. Also you need to account for the capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

maybe if you have little words you can use elif or or

```
if a=="exit":
    exit()
elif a=="optionOne":
     doSomething
else:
    print "word not alowed"
```

Or you can do like this

```
if a=="exit" or a=="notAllowedWord":
    exit()
```